# Material-UI multiple table collapse/expand

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make a collapsible table using MateialUI Currently, my slides all have collapses but they are linked to one state for "open" so if I open one slide, all the other slide open.

here a sansbox:https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-bash-e1mzu?file=/src/components/BrandTable.js

The props array of objects needs a collapsible table for each slide which I have.

```js
const props = [
            {slide: "Protein", charts: ["Keto"]},
            {slide: "Bars with benefits - beyond the nutritional profile", charts: ["Innovative approaches"]},
            {slide: "Vegan", charts: []}
          ]

        return (
        <div>
        
        
       
        {
       
          props.map((blog) => 
          
          <React.Fragment>
        <TableRow  key={props} >
          <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
            {blog.slide}
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell size="small">
            <IconButton aria-label="expand row" size="small" onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
              {open ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon/>}
            </IconButton>
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow> 
        <TableRow>
         <TableCell style={{ paddingBottom: 0, paddingTop: 0 }} colSpan={6}>
          <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                {
                    open &&   <Box margin={1}>
                    <Table size="small" aria-label="purchases">
                      <TableBody>
                      {blog.charts}
                      </TableBody>
  
                    </Table>
                  </Box>
                }
                </Collapse>
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
          }

      </React.Fragment>
          
          
          
          )
        }
       
            </div> 

            

    )
}
```

Comment: Move the iteration out the `Row` component [or] use row id for tracking the open/close status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can track the open/close status by maintaining a local state like below,

```
 const [open, setOpen] = React.useState({});
```

And update based on the item click with the id,

```
 <IconButton
              aria-label="expand row"
              size="small"
              onClick={() =>
                setOpen((prev) => ({ ...prev, [blog.id]: !prev[blog.id] }))
              }
            >
```

Row component:-

```
const Row = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        {props.map((blog) => (
          <React.Fragment>
            <TableRow key={props}>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {blog.slide}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell size="small">
                <IconButton
                  aria-label="expand row"
                  size="small"
                  onClick={() =>
                    setOpen((prev) => ({ ...prev, [blog.id]: !prev[blog.id] }))
                  }
                >
                  {open[blog.id] ? (
                    <KeyboardArrowUpIcon />
                  ) : (
                    <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />
                  )}
                </IconButton>
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell
                style={{ paddingBottom: 0, paddingTop: 0 }}
                colSpan={6}
              >
                <Collapse in={open[blog.id]} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                  {open[blog.id] && (
                    <Box margin={1}>
                      <Table size="small" aria-label="purchases">
                        <TableBody>{blog.charts}</TableBody>
                      </Table>
                    </Box>
                  )}
                </Collapse>
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-chatelet-m9emk?file=/src/components/BrandTable.js:1101-2543

Answer (score 0):

Please try to see this example here:
[https://codesandbox.io/s/kbcee](https://codesandbox.io/s/kbcee?file=/demo.js)

I think you can store active id of expanded row instead of open/close state only. Or you can create `Row` component where open state will be used only inside a component each time .